# How much code is too much code to put into a question?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

So, I've recently seen a lot of cases where questions have mostly code written on them rather than actual information that can be used to solve the problem.  There's been people posting plenty of code where it just seems as though they want it redone by someone else.  It barely feels as if it's a question.  Rather, it feels as though it's a job someone wants done for them.

I've had instances where I was told in the comments to post the full code of a certain class/multiple classes.  I feel nervous when I do something like this though, it feels like I'm giving an overdose of information and useless code that won't help to solve my problem.

What kinds of things should be done with cases such as these?

I've considered:

- **Linking the full code**

  Just adding a link to another site where the code is.  Something like Pastebin or any other sites that can do things such as what Pastebin does to remove clutter with the question and actually get it answered.
- **Creating only a working copy**

  Doing something like this can reduce clutter, but it may not get the answer you need.  Sometimes full code needs to be pasted in order to actually find where the problem is.  If I'm creating a working copy of where I think the problem is sprouting, people may still need more information to figure out what the problem is.  This requires me to put even more information in the question.
- **Pasting the full code in the question**

  This is something that I'd do as a last resort.  It really risks my question getting downvotes because of what I mentioned before.  It seems like I want someone to do the job for me.

The rules here on Stack Overflow can be really strict sometimes.  This can be really intimidating sometimes for people new to programming such as myself.

Comment: What part of http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve you need clarification with?

Comment: 'adding a link' no, links go stale, and you will be down and close-voted.  'Sometimes full code needs to be pasted in order to actually find where the problem is' - you did not do any, or insufficient, debugging before posting, you will get down and close voted.  If the problem is so complex that it cannot be MCVE'd, then it's a bad filt for SO, and you should troubleshoot it on your own - we cannot help.

Comment: I try to edit a old question just to highlight the code source and I was told: "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." Why editing question is blocking my attempt to make it more readable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to post *just* enough code to reproduce the problem behavior.

See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I also recommend any code output errors to help narrow down where the breakage is.